# htaccess multi rss feed redirection with language variable

Tags: url, .htaccess, redirect

I have a multilingual blog, default language is Italian and second language is English.
So I have 2 RSS feeds:

- `/feed`
- `/feed/?lang=en`

The first points to Italian the second to English.
I wanna both redirect to Feedburner using .htaccess, the first should point to `http://feeds.feedburner.com/SimoBlog` and the second to `http://feeds.feedburner.com/digitalking/haPl`

I successfully done it for the first with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(FeedBurner|FeedValidator) [NC]
RewriteRule ^feed/?.*$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/SimoBlog [L,NC,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

I don't figure out to make it working also for the second feed URL, any help?

Thanks, Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the query string is equal to `lang=en`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(FeedBurner|FeedValidator) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=lang=en
RewriteRule ^feed/?$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/SimoBlog [L,NC,R=302]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(FeedBurner|FeedValidator) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =lang=en
RewriteRule ^feed/?$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/digitalking/haPl [L,NC,R=302]
```